# Xcode App crash only on device - EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: swift, logging, crash, device, sigabrt

My app crashes only when I try to run it on my Iphone but doesn't on the simulator, I don't understand how to read a crash log could somebody give me a hint? In Xcode the app crashes at `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` with the signal SIGABRT

```
Incident Identifier: 8FF053DB-175C-40E8-9D9C-BD7B357BE6D4
CrashReporter Key:   dc449591e2b211cdba4d3655b320f72f9d475cc7
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:             com.zeghetusa.hungrybird [17612]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/72EBA21E-94CB-4840-9A82-9B5B161C06ED/com.zeghetusa.hungrybird.app/com.zeghetusa.hungrybird
Identifier:          com.zeghetusa.hungrybird
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      debugserver [17611]

Date/Time:           2015-04-08 17:49:07.247 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D169)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30a37fce __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1e4cca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30a3b86e +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30a3a24e ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x309897f4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000f8d48 0xb7000 + 269640
6   com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000ebfe0 0xb7000 + 217056
7   com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000efea8 0xb7000 + 233128
8   com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fb404 0xb7000 + 279556
9   com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fb94c 0xb7000 + 280908
10  UIKit                           0x332584c6 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
11  UIKit                           0x33258284 -[UIViewController view] + 20
12  UIKit                           0x33377b1e -[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:] + 698
13  UIKit                           0x332ded2a +[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:] + 234
14  UIKit                           0x333df2ca __79-[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]_block_invoke + 126
15  UIKit                           0x332893c0 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 492
16  UIKit                           0x333c1ab2 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 66
17  UIKit                           0x333046bc -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 460
18  UIKit                           0x3325f348 -[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance] + 244
19  UIKit                           0x3325c7fc -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 228
20  UIKit                           0x332c6358 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
21  UIKit                           0x332c2fc8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1816
22  UIKit                           0x332bd586 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 710
23  UIKit                           0x33259704 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3536
24  UIKit                           0x3325886c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
25  UIKit                           0x332bccc4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
26  GraphicsServices                0x35871ae8 _PurpleEventCallback + 604
27  GraphicsServices                0x358716d2 PurpleEventCallback + 30
28  CoreFoundation                  0x30a02ab2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
29  CoreFoundation                  0x30a02a4e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
30  CoreFoundation                  0x30a01222 __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3096bf4a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3096bd2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
33  UIKit                           0x332bbeec -[UIApplication _run] + 756
34  UIKit                           0x332b7168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
35  com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fd164 0xb7000 + 287076
36  com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fd1a0 0xb7000 + 287136
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b6f1ab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7a71f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b811792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b757fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3aa86cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3aa9f6e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1e4f62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3aa9d1c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3aa9cd28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1e4e12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3096bfc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3096bd2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  UIKit                           0x332bbeec -[UIApplication _run] + 756
12  UIKit                           0x332b7168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fd164 0xb7000 + 287076
14  com.zeghetusa.hungrybird        0x000fd1a0 0xb7000 + 287136
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b6f1ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7a7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7a7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  gputools.smt_poll.0x14d341b0
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7a7544 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b718988 nanosleep + 168
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b7188d6 usleep + 46
3   GPUToolsCore                    0x0077af34 0x777000 + 16180
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b810916 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b810886 _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80eaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7a7c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b80ea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b794808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b6e0de8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b6cff6e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3d51018c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d4c474
    r8: 0x14d93610    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00101dd3     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d4c468      lr: 0x3b811797      pc: 0x3b7a71f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
```

Comment: Apparently you send a wrong object to a selector and so it's throwing the `doesNotRecognizeSelector` error. Have you tried cleaning and building it again? You should set breakpoints in your `rootViewController` everywhere.

Comment: are you using the same iOS version in the simulator and the physical device?

Comment: Yeah the build device is 7.1 so i guess the simulator has the newest version. I tried adding breakpoints and it crashes at  let:playerCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

Comment: It seems that it crashes on the simulator too only if the breakpoints are activated

Comment: Simulator 7.1 crashes but not the newest version which crashes only if the breakpoints are activated.

Answer (score 0):

turns out my error was "Specifically init(fileNamed:) its only Available in iOS 8.0 and later."